# How to send transaction using web3py using infura.io

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py, infura

I have connected to mainnet via

> infura.io

and have used  http provider for connections now

- i want to generate address

  and
- send transaction

And i wand to send real eth

so how can i do this?I have used web3 py for connection Is it that i have to connect to local node

- And is it neccesary to deploy contract to send transaction

I have create account and generate address:

```
acct = Account.create('xxxxxxxxx')
print(acct.address)
```

So what are these addresses and how can i transfer balance using this address

Any help would be greatly appreciated